# Eliminate Root Entity in the DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have an XML structure like 
        [XML Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flapr.png)

I am inserting the data from this XML into tables using Entity and `DBContext`.

My Entity:

```
   [Serializable]    
   public class Root
    {        
        [Key]
        public int Key1 { get; set; }
        public int Key2 { get; set; }      
        [XmlElement("Parent")]
        [ForeignKey("Key2")]
        public List<Parent> liParent{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent
    {        
        [Key]
        public int Key1 { get; set; }
        public int Key2 { get; set; }       
        [XmlElement("child")]
        [ForeignKey("Key2")]
        public List<child> lichild{ get; set; }
    }

    public class child
    {        
        [Key]
        public int Key1 { get; set; }       
        public int object1{get; set;}
        public int object2 {get; set;}
    }
```

In the above Root is just used to maintain a list based on parent and assign the seqno, i dont want to insert the data in Root to any table. But while executing the datacontext it is trying to insert the data into table with the class name "Roots" and returning an error:

> Invalid object name Roots

How can i eliminate the code to consider inserting Root?

DBContextCode:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
      Database.SetInitializer<DBContext>(null);            
      modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().ToTable("Table1");
      modelBuilder.Entity<child>().ToTable("Table2");    
 }
```

XML Handling Code:

```
Root clsRoot;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sFilePath))
{
    clsRoot = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}


int RNo = 1;
clsRoot.liParent.ForEach(X =>
{
    X.RecNo = RNo++;
    int sRNo = 1;
    X.lichild.ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.RecNo = sRNo++;
            x.ParentRecNo = X.RecNo;
        });
});

using (var dbContext = new DBContext())
{
    dbContext.Root.Add(clsRoot);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Can we see your xml handling code?

Comment: Hi KiNeTiC,

i have added the XML handling code in the above.

Comment: Why do you have a "Root" DbSet in your context if you don't need it in the first place?

Comment: And I don't think the foreign keys in your parent and root classes make sense.